# what is the mean of * and flatten in ruby

Tags: ruby, flatten

I am new to ruby language so when I was trying to sort a hash by value 
I used this method to sort:

```
movie_popularity.sort_by{|m,p| p}.reverse
```

but the the sort method returns an array while I need a hash to be returned so I used this command:

```
movie_popularity=Hash[*movie_popularity.sort_by{|m,p| p}.reverse.flatten]
```

my Question is what is the meaning of `*` and `flatten` in the above line?

Thanks =)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `*` is called the "splat operator"; I'm not sure I could give you the technical definition (though I'm sure you'd find it soon enough with Google's help), but the way I'd describe it is that it basically takes the place of hand-writing multiple comma-separated values in code.

To make this more concrete, consider the case of `Hash[]` which you've used in your example. The `Hash` class has a `[]` class method which takes a variable number of arguments and can normally be called like this:

```
# Returns { "foo" => 1, "bar" => 2 }
h = Hash["foo", 1, "bar", 2]
```

Notice how that isn't an array or a hash or anything that I passed in; it's a (hand-written) sequence of values. The `*` operator allows you to achieve basically the same thing using an array--in your case, the one returned by `movie_popularity.sort_by{|m,p| p}.reverse.flatten`.

As for that `flatten` call: when you call `sort_by` on a hash, you're really leveraging the `Enumerable` module which is included in a variety of classes (most notably `Array` and `Hash`) that provide enumeration. In the case of a hash, you've probably noticed that instead of iterating over one like this:

```
hash.each { |value| ... }
```

Instead you do this:

```
hash.each { |key, value| ... }
```

That is, iterating over a hash yields *two* values on each iteration. So your `sort_by` call on its own would return a sequence of *pairs*. Calling `flatten` on this result collapses the pairs into a one-dimensional sequence of values, like this:

```
# Returns [1, 2, 3, 4]
[[1, 2], [3, 4]].flatten
```

Answer (score 3):

'flatten' flattens an array: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-flatten

'*' is the splat operator: http://theplana.wordpress.com/2007/03/03/ruby-idioms-the-splat-operator/

The pertinent bit in the last url is this:

```
a = [[:planes, 21], [:cars, 36]]
h = Hash[*a]  # => { :planes=>21, :cars=>36}
```